# How, in Sinatra, to pass a Request Body to other classes?

Tags: json, request, sinatra

I'm using a Sinatra app to receive server requests and I want to dissect them in a separate class I call "request", but when I pass the request object the body gets dropped.  Trying to read the request.body in the main class works but trying to read it in the new class generates a JSONparser octet error.

In the main Sinatra file, this test call generates the correct response:

```
puts JSON.parse request.body.read
```

after, I pass the request to the Request Class with the code below.

```
req=Request.new(request)
```

But in the Request class initialization def, the same "puts" code above generates the error:

```
JSON::ParserError - A JSON text must at least contain two octets!:
```

Both files include the JSON requirement.

A work around is fairly simple but I would prefer the more elegant solution if I could figure out why it is not working as I expect.  Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I didn't think Sinatra ever had a problem requesting a body with class.

Answer (score 0):

from my tests
  the Request.new constructor doesn't seem to clone from Request object

request.clone works proper

you need to do the thorough object inspection if you need anything extreme

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I tried  your suggestion, but when I create a new Request object, opposed to the Sinatra request object, the cloning doesn't seem to work either.  In this case, I am using the following code:"req=Request.new(request.clone)".  Is that what you meant?